# Resetting Pagination on AJAX destroy

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am using will_paginate for paginating my results. Most of my site is AJAXified. All the records in the view can be edited/deleted in place. These records are paginated. I would like to know if there is any way to reset the pagination on AJAX destroy.

For example, say i have 20 records, with 5 records shown per page. If the user deletes a record, i would want the pagination links to reset accordingly. Also, i would have to pull in the next record onto the current page and display it in place of the deleted record. I just wanted to know if there was some gem/plugin available that could do the same. If not i would have to make one myself.

Is there any other alternative to the design approach that i am using? Perhaps something on the lines of Twitter/Buzz/Tumblr pagination? Or is there something you have come across which is better/cooler way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that just reloading the div holding the 5 records and the pagination is not an option.

If this is the case, on the destroy method, you could also append a new record and reload the pagination.

```
def destroy
  # destroy record 
  ...
  #reload records for current page    
  @models = MyModel.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  render :update do |page|
    #remove record div
    ...
    new_record_to_append = @models[MyModel.per_page - 1]
    #append the last record to the page
    page.insert_html(:bottom, 'content', :partial => 'my_partial', :object => new_record_to_append) if new_record_to_append
    #replace pagination
    page.replace 'pagination', :partial => 'pagination_partial'
  end
end
```